# Convert two txt files to single XML File

Tags: php, xml, merge

I receive two text files daily. One has vehicle info and the other has dealer info. I the scripts below unsing XMLWriter to convert them to xml. Is there a way to use parse both txt files into one XML document using a common node? The common node is FRANCHISE_ID.

I use the following scripts to convert them to xml:

```
<?php
$data = fopen('dealers_retail.txt', 'r');
    $xml = new XMLWriter;
    $xml->openURI('dealers_retail.xml');
    $xml->setIndent(true); // makes output cleaner
    $xml->startElement('DATA');
    $flag = true;
    while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, '|')) {
        if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
       $xml->startElement('ITEM');
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_ID', $line[0]);
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_NAME', str_replace("~", "", $line[1]));
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_ADDRESS', str_replace("~", "", $line[2]));
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_CITY', str_replace("~", "", $line[3]));
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_STATE', str_replace("~", "", $line[4]));
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_ZIP', str_replace("~", "", $line[5]));
       $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
?>
```

**Which outputs:**

```
<DATA>
 <ITEM>
  <FRANCHISE_ID>12345</FRANCHISE_ID>
  <FRANCHISE_NAME>Mercedes-Benz of XXX</FRANCHISE_NAME>
  <FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>2915 Some Street</FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>
  <FRANCHISE_CITY>Oakland</FRANCHISE_CITY>
  <FRANCHISE_STATE>CA</FRANCHISE_STATE>
  <FRANCHISE_ZIP>94611</FRANCHISE_ZIP>
 </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

**AND**

```
<?php
$data = fopen('inventory_retail.txt', 'r');
    $xml = new XMLWriter;
    $xml->openURI('inventory_retail.xml');
    $xml->setIndent(true); // makes output cleaner
    $xml->startElement('DATA');
    $flag = true;
    while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, '|')) {
        if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
       $xml->startElement('ITEM');
       $xml->writeElement('FRANCHISE_ID', $line[0]);
       $xml->writeElement('VEHICLE_VIN', str_replace("~", "", $line[1]));
       $xml->writeElement('LISTING_ID', str_replace("~", "", $line[1]));
       $xml->writeElement('LIST_PRICE', str_replace("~", "", $line[2]));
       $xml->writeElement('VEHICLE_YEAR', str_replace("~", "", $line[3]));
       $xml->writeElement('MAKE_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[4]));
       $xml->writeElement('MODEL_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[5]));
       $xml->writeElement('TRIM', str_replace("~", "", $line[6]));
       $xml->writeElement('SKU', str_replace("~", "", $line[7]));
       $xml->writeElement('BODY_TYPE', str_replace("~", "", $line[8]));
       $xml->writeElement('ADF_BODY_TYPE', str_replace("~", "", $line[8]));
       $xml->writeElement('DRIVE_TYPE', str_replace("~", "", $line[9]));
       $xml->writeElement('ENGINE_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[10]));
       $xml->writeElement('VEHICLE_FUEL_TYPE', str_replace("~", "", $line[11]));
       $xml->writeElement('TRANSMISSION', str_replace("~", "", $line[12]));
       $xml->writeElement('ADF_TRANSMISSION', str_replace("~", "", $line[12]));
       $xml->writeElement('MILEAGE', str_replace("~", "", $line[13]));
       $xml->writeElement('NUMBER_OF_CYLINDERS', str_replace("~", "", $line[14]));
       $xml->writeElement('NUMBER_OF_DOORS', str_replace("~", "", $line[15]));
       $xml->writeElement('COLOR_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[16]));
       $xml->writeElement('INTERIOR_COLOR', str_replace("~", "", $line[17]));
       $xml->writeElement('INTERIOR_TYPE', str_replace("~", "", $line[18]));
       $xml->writeElement('REFERENCE_DATE', str_replace("~", "", $line[19]));
       $xml->writeElement('OPTIONS_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[20]));
       $xml->writeElement('AUDIO_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[21]));
       $xml->writeElement('SUN_ROOF', str_replace("~", "", $line[22]));
       $xml->writeElement('ALARM_SYSTEM', str_replace("~", "", $line[23]));     
       $xml->writeElement('POWER_WINDOWS', str_replace("~", "", $line[24]));
       $xml->writeElement('POWER_LOCKS', str_replace("~", "", $line[25]));
       $xml->writeElement('AIRBAGS', str_replace("~", "", $line[26]));
       $xml->writeElement('AIR_CONDITIONING', str_replace("~", "", $line[27]));
       $xml->writeElement('CRUISE_CONTROL', str_replace("~", "", $line[28]));
       $xml->writeElement('TILT_STEERING', str_replace("~", "", $line[29]));
       $xml->writeElement('POWER_STEERING', str_replace("~", "", $line[30]));
       $xml->writeElement('POWER_SEATS', str_replace("~", "", $line[31]));
       $xml->writeElement('PROMOTIONAL_TEXT', str_replace("~", "", $line[32]));
       $xml->writeElement('OEM_CERTIFIED', str_replace("~", "", $line[33]));
       $xml->writeElement('WARRANTY_DESC', str_replace("~", "", $line[34]));
       $xml->writeElement('PHOTO_AVAILABLE_FLAG', str_replace("~", "", $line[35]));     
       $xml->writeElement('PHOTO_URL', str_replace("~", "", $line[36]));    
       $xml->writeElement('SELLER_TYPE', seller_type_cdcretail);    
       $xml->writeElement('CONDITION_RADIO', used);
       $xml->writeElement('CONDITION_CHECKBOX', used);
       $xml->writeElement('ADF_CONDITION', used);
       $xml->writeElement('USE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS', 1);
       $xml->writeElement('COUNTRY', 'united states');
       $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
?>
```

**Which outputs:**

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <FRANCHISE_ID>12345</FRANCHISE_ID>
    <VEHICLE_VIN>12345678901234567</VEHICLE_VIN>
    <LISTING_ID>12345678901234567</LISTING_ID>
    <LIST_PRICE>47986</LIST_PRICE>
    <VEHICLE_YEAR>2019</VEHICLE_YEAR>
    <MAKE_DESC>Mercedes-Benz</MAKE_DESC>
    <MODEL_DESC>E-Class</MODEL_DESC>
    <TRIM>E 300</TRIM>
    <SKU>9999999999</SKU>
    <BODY_TYPE>4dr Car</BODY_TYPE>
    <ADF_BODY_TYPE>4dr Car</ADF_BODY_TYPE>
    <DRIVE_TYPE>RWD</DRIVE_TYPE>
    <ENGINE_DESC>Intercooled Turbo Premium Unleaded I-4 2.0 L/121</ENGINE_DESC>
    <VEHICLE_FUEL_TYPE/>
    <TRANSMISSION>9-Speed Automatic w/OD</TRANSMISSION>
    <ADF_TRANSMISSION>9-Speed Automatic w/OD</ADF_TRANSMISSION>
    <MILEAGE>7446</MILEAGE>
    <NUMBER_OF_CYLINDERS/>
    <NUMBER_OF_DOORS>4</NUMBER_OF_DOORS>
    <COLOR_DESC>White</COLOR_DESC>
    <INTERIOR_COLOR>Black Leather</INTERIOR_COLOR>
    <INTERIOR_TYPE/>
    <REFERENCE_DATE/>
    <OPTIONS_DESC>Turbocharged, Rear Wheel Drive</OPTIONS_DESC>
    <AUDIO_DESC/>
    <SUN_ROOF/>
    <ALARM_SYSTEM/>
    <POWER_WINDOWS/>
    <POWER_LOCKS/>
    <AIRBAGS/>
    <AIR_CONDITIONING/>
    <CRUISE_CONTROL/>
    <TILT_STEERING/>
    <POWER_STEERING/>
    <POWER_SEATS/>
    <PROMOTIONAL_TEXT>PRICE REDUCED, CERTIFIED</PROMOTIONAL_TEXT>
    <OEM_CERTIFIED>0</OEM_CERTIFIED>
    <WARRANTY_DESC/>
    <PHOTO_AVAILABLE_FLAG>1</PHOTO_AVAILABLE_FLAG>
    <PHOTO_URL>http://content.jpg</PHOTO_URL>
    <SELLER_TYPE>seller_type_cdcretail</SELLER_TYPE>
    <CONDITION_RADIO>used</CONDITION_RADIO>
    <CONDITION_CHECKBOX>used</CONDITION_CHECKBOX>
    <ADF_CONDITION>used</ADF_CONDITION>
    <USE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>1</USE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>
    <COUNTRY>united states</COUNTRY>
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

**I want to achieve the following output:**

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <FRANCHISE_ID>12345</FRANCHISE_ID>
    <VEHICLE_VIN>12345678901234567</VEHICLE_VIN>
    <LISTING_ID>12345678901234567</LISTING_ID>
    <LIST_PRICE>47986</LIST_PRICE>
    <VEHICLE_YEAR>2019</VEHICLE_YEAR>
    <MAKE_DESC>Mercedes-Benz</MAKE_DESC>
    <MODEL_DESC>E-Class</MODEL_DESC>
    <TRIM>E 300</TRIM>
    <SKU>9999999999</SKU>
    <BODY_TYPE>4dr Car</BODY_TYPE>
    <ADF_BODY_TYPE>4dr Car</ADF_BODY_TYPE>
    <DRIVE_TYPE>RWD</DRIVE_TYPE>
    <ENGINE_DESC>Intercooled Turbo Premium Unleaded I-4 2.0 L/121</ENGINE_DESC>
    <VEHICLE_FUEL_TYPE/>
    <TRANSMISSION>9-Speed Automatic w/OD</TRANSMISSION>
    <ADF_TRANSMISSION>9-Speed Automatic w/OD</ADF_TRANSMISSION>
    <MILEAGE>7446</MILEAGE>
    <NUMBER_OF_CYLINDERS/>
    <NUMBER_OF_DOORS>4</NUMBER_OF_DOORS>
    <COLOR_DESC>White</COLOR_DESC>
    <INTERIOR_COLOR>Black Leather</INTERIOR_COLOR>
    <INTERIOR_TYPE/>
    <REFERENCE_DATE/>
    <OPTIONS_DESC>Turbocharged, Rear Wheel Drive</OPTIONS_DESC>
    <AUDIO_DESC/>
    <SUN_ROOF/>
    <ALARM_SYSTEM/>
    <POWER_WINDOWS/>
    <POWER_LOCKS/>
    <AIRBAGS/>
    <AIR_CONDITIONING/>
    <CRUISE_CONTROL/>
    <TILT_STEERING/>
    <POWER_STEERING/>
    <POWER_SEATS/>
    <PROMOTIONAL_TEXT>PRICE REDUCED, CERTIFIED</PROMOTIONAL_TEXT>
    <OEM_CERTIFIED>0</OEM_CERTIFIED>
    <WARRANTY_DESC/>
    <PHOTO_AVAILABLE_FLAG>1</PHOTO_AVAILABLE_FLAG>
    <PHOTO_URL>http://content.jpg</PHOTO_URL>
    <SELLER_TYPE>seller_type_cdcretail</SELLER_TYPE>
    <CONDITION_RADIO>used</CONDITION_RADIO>
    <CONDITION_CHECKBOX>used</CONDITION_CHECKBOX>
    <ADF_CONDITION>used</ADF_CONDITION>
    <USE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>1</USE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>
    <COUNTRY>united states</COUNTRY>
    <FRANCHISE_NAME>Mercedes-Benz of XXX</FRANCHISE_NAME>
    <FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>2915 Some Street</FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>
    <FRANCHISE_CITY>Oakland</FRANCHISE_CITY>
    <FRANCHISE_STATE>CA</FRANCHISE_STATE>
    <FRANCHISE_ZIP>94611</FRANCHISE_ZIP>
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

I tried the following which only copies the dealer data to the first vehicle belonging to that dealer. I'm lost at how to apply it to each vehicle for that particular dealer:

```
<?php

$data = fopen('usacarshopucr_used_inventory_retail.txt', 'r');
// Skip header
fgetcsv($data, 0, '|');
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<DATA />");
// Array which translates the field name to the field in the input file
$itemData = ['FRANCHISE_ID' => 0, 'VEHICLE_VIN' => 1, 'LISTING_ID' => 1,
    'LIST_PRICE' => 2, 'VEHICLE_YEAR' => 3,
    'MAKE_DESC' => 4, 'MODEL_DESC' => 5
];

while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, '|')) {
    $item = $xml->addChild("ITEM");
    // Copy the data from the input file to the XML
    foreach ( $itemData as $name => $itemElement )   {
        $item->addChild($name, str_replace("~", "", $line[$itemElement]));
    }
}

$data = fopen('usacarshopucr_used_dealers_retail.txt', 'r');
fgetcsv($data, 0, '|');

// You will need to add all of the fields in here, this is just to show
// how to start.  Don't add the fields with a fixed value, these are added
// in separately
$itemData = ['FRANCHISE_NAME' => 1,
    'FRANCHISE_ADDRESS' => 2, 'FRANCHISE_CITY' => 3,
    'FRANCHISE_STATE' => 4, 'FRANCHISE_ZIP' => 5
];
while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, '|')) {
    // Find the matching item in the existing XML for the FRANCHISE_ID
    $item = $xml->xpath('//ITEM[FRANCHISE_ID="'.$line[0].'"]')[0];
    // Copy the data from the input file to the XML
    foreach ( $itemData as $name => $itemElement )   {
        $item->addChild($name, str_replace("~", "", $line[$itemElement]));
    }

    // Add in fixed data - again finish this part off
    $item->addChild('CONDITION_RADIO', 'used');
    $item->addChild('ADF_CONDITION', 'used');
}
$xml->asXML('simple_inventory_retail-2.xml');

?>
```

It outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
    <ITEM>
        <FRANCHISE_ID>236057</FRANCHISE_ID>
        <VEHICLE_VIN>4JGDF6EE4GA708047</VEHICLE_VIN>
        <LISTING_ID>4JGDF6EE4GA708047</LISTING_ID>
        <LIST_PRICE>39300</LIST_PRICE>
        <VEHICLE_YEAR>2016</VEHICLE_YEAR>
        <MAKE_DESC>Mercedes-Benz</MAKE_DESC>
        <MODEL_DESC>GL</MODEL_DESC>
        <FRANCHISE_NAME>Malone's Automotive</FRANCHISE_NAME>
        <FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>1827 Lower Roswell Road</FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>
        <FRANCHISE_CITY>Marietta</FRANCHISE_CITY>
        <FRANCHISE_STATE>GA</FRANCHISE_STATE>
        <FRANCHISE_ZIP>30068</FRANCHISE_ZIP>
        <CONDITION_RADIO>used</CONDITION_RADIO>
        <ADF_CONDITION>used</ADF_CONDITION>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <FRANCHISE_ID>236057</FRANCHISE_ID>
        <VEHICLE_VIN>WA1L2AFP5GA039814</VEHICLE_VIN>
        <LISTING_ID>WA1L2AFP5GA039814</LISTING_ID>
        <LIST_PRICE>26990</LIST_PRICE>
        <VEHICLE_YEAR>2016</VEHICLE_YEAR>
        <MAKE_DESC>Audi</MAKE_DESC>
        <MODEL_DESC>Q5</MODEL_DESC>
    </ITEM>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses SimpleXML to create the files, rather than try and merge the output, this in one process will read dealers file, create the details from there and then read the inventory file and add the details in...

(Updated to read the dealers into an array and then write the details out in one go to the XML file).

```
$data = fopen('dealers_retail.txt', 'r');
// Skip header
fgetcsv($data, 0, '|');

// Store dealer information
$dealers = [];
while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, '|')) {
    $dealers [$line[0]] = $line;
}
fclose($data);

$xml = simplexml_load_string("<Data />");

$data = fopen('inventory_retail.txt', 'r');
fgetcsv($data, 0, '|');

$dealerData = ['FRANCHISE_ID' => 0, 'FRANCHISE_NAME' => 1,
    'FRANCHISE_ADDRESS' => 2, 'FRANCHISE_CITY' => 3,
    'FRANCHISE_STATE' => 4, 'FRANCHISE_ZIP' => 5
];

// You will need to add all of the fields in here, this is just to show
// how to start.  Don't add the fields with a fixed value, these are added
// in separately
$itemData = ['VEHICLE_VIN' => 1, 'LISTING_ID' => 1,
    'LIST_PRICE' => 2, 'VEHICLE_YEAR' => 3,
    'MAKE_DESC' => 4, 'MODEL_DESC' => 5
];
while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, '|')) {
    // Add in dealer data
    $item = $xml->addChild("ITEM");
    $dealer = $dealers[$line[0]];
    foreach ( $dealerData as $name => $itemElement )   {
        $item->addChild($name, str_replace("~", "", $dealer[$itemElement]));
    }
    // Copy the data from the vehicle file to the XML
    foreach ( $itemData as $name => $itemElement )   {
        $item->addChild($name, str_replace("~", "", $line[$itemElement]));
    }

    // Add in fixed data - again finish this part off
    $item->addChild('CONDITION_RADIO', 'used');
    $item->addChild('ADF_CONDITION', 'used');
}
$xml->asXML('inventory_retail.xml');
```

generates

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
    <ITEM>
        <FRANCHISE_ID>12345</FRANCHISE_ID>
        <FRANCHISE_NAME>Mercedes-Benz of XXX</FRANCHISE_NAME>
        <FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>2915 Some Street</FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>
        <FRANCHISE_CITY>Oakland</FRANCHISE_CITY>
        <FRANCHISE_STATE>CA</FRANCHISE_STATE>
        <FRANCHISE_ZIP>94611</FRANCHISE_ZIP>
        <VEHICLE_VIN>12345678901234567</VEHICLE_VIN>
        <LISTING_ID>12345678901234567</LISTING_ID>
        <LIST_PRICE>47986</LIST_PRICE>
        <VEHICLE_YEAR>2019</VEHICLE_YEAR>
        <MAKE_DESC>Mercedes-Benz</MAKE_DESC>
        <MODEL_DESC>E-Class</MODEL_DESC>
        <CONDITION_RADIO>used</CONDITION_RADIO>
        <ADF_CONDITION>used</ADF_CONDITION>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <FRANCHISE_ID>12345</FRANCHISE_ID>
        <FRANCHISE_NAME>Mercedes-Benz of XXX</FRANCHISE_NAME>
        <FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>2915 Some Street</FRANCHISE_ADDRESS>
        <FRANCHISE_CITY>Oakland</FRANCHISE_CITY>
        <FRANCHISE_STATE>CA</FRANCHISE_STATE>
        <FRANCHISE_ZIP>94611</FRANCHISE_ZIP>
        <VEHICLE_VIN>12345678901234568</VEHICLE_VIN>
        <LISTING_ID>12345678901234568</LISTING_ID>
        <LIST_PRICE>47986</LIST_PRICE>
        <VEHICLE_YEAR>2019</VEHICLE_YEAR>
        <MAKE_DESC>Mercedes-Benz</MAKE_DESC>
        <MODEL_DESC>E-Class</MODEL_DESC>
        <CONDITION_RADIO>used</CONDITION_RADIO>
        <ADF_CONDITION>used</ADF_CONDITION>
    </ITEM>
</Data>
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way for this to post the dealer data in each of the corresponding inventory ITEM? Current, the data is only copied to the first ITEM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can merge 2 arrays from 2 incoming files into one, and only after that create the xml file.

```
$flag = true;

$mergedArray = [];  // this array will contain all data
// insert data from first file
while ($line = fgetcsv($data_from_first_file, 0, '|')) {
    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
     $mergedArray[$line[0]]['FRANCHISE_ID'] = $line[0];
     // and so on ...

}
// insert data from second file
$flag = true;

while ($line = fgetcsv($data_from_second_file, 0, '|')) {
    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
     $mergedArray[$line[0]]['VEHICLE_VIN'] =  str_replace("~", "", $line[1]);
     // and so on ...

}
// now just foreach over the array to create the XML
// ...
$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('dealers_retail.xml');
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('DATA');

foreach($mergedArray as $item=>$data){
    $xml->startElement('ITEM');
    foreach($data as $index=>$value){
       $xml->writeElement($index, $value);
    }
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help with this. This creates an xml file with each dealer and includes one vehicle. In the txt files, there are 141 dealers and 140,000vehicles. I'm trying to manipulate this to show each vehicle in the xml file but also include the dealer info within the vehicle <ITEM>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest importing the CSV files into a database first. If you don't have a database server use SQLite. You might be able to use some CLI tool for this. In a PHP script you could collect several data items and insert them at once to archive a balance between memory and cpu usage.

After you have the database you can easily use a JOIN to get an aggregated result and output the XML using XMLWriter.

Additionally you get the possibility to generate filtered or limited results.

Comment: Hi, would this allow the dealer data to be copied to every vehicle?

Comment: SQL allows to join tables to produce the result: `SELECT * FROM listings, franchises WHERE franchises.franchise_id = listings.franchise_id`

Comment: Hi ThW, Thanks for you help.